# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

i am doing a little project in laravel with Ajax but i have got this error when i do the validations with ajax.

[image: dashboard]

```html
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click','.add_product', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let name= $('#name').val();
        let price= $('#price').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: {{ route('add') }},
            method: 'post',
            data: {name:name, price:price},
            success: function(res) { },
            error: function(err) {
                let error = err.responseJSON;

                $.each(error.errors, function(index, value) {
                    $('.errMsgContainer').append('<span class="text-danger">'+ value+ '</span>' + '<br>');
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Which specific line does the error point to?  This looks suspect: `url:{{ route('add') }}`  Is this the actual client-side code you're using?  Or some server-side template which gets replaced with a value?  If the former, this is indeed invalid JavaScript code.  If the latter, what is the actual resulting JavaScript code you're using?  Additionally, if you start consistently formatting/indenting your code then you'll be able to spot mis-matched elements more easily.

Comment: Where in the code is that error thrown? Is it in the JS or when you parse your JSON response? Pease narrow the issue down (or if you have, tell us exactly when and where the error occurs).

Comment: Make sure that the code above is in a file ending with `.blade.php`, so that the blade interpreter can evaluate `{{ route('add') }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside the ajax in the url make it like this

```
URL: "{{ route('add') }}",
```

add the route inside quotations.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(document).on('click', '.add_product', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let name = $('#name').val();
                let price = $('#price').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('add') }}",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name: name,
                        price: price
                    },
                    success: function(res) {

                    },
                    error: function(err) {

                        let error = err.responseJSON;
                        $.each(error.errors, function(index, value) {
                            $('.errMsgContainer').append('<span class="text-danger">' + value + '</span>' + '<br>')
                        });
                    }
                });


            })

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: at leats it worked, i did it like you said and it works, but now i have got another error but i think this time  it´s about logical or some error with the url, because the program is running but dont make the validation.

Comment: where is your validation are they inside your HTML form?

Comment: i have the validation in the  Controller, also in my product_js.blade.php with Ajax  give a second and i´ll put my code here or  in another question.

Comment: ok please put the link so i could see

Comment: no problem any time you added just share the link

Comment: ok thanks man i´ll show you the link as fast as i can

Comment: Hi sr here you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75021103/ajax-send-this-error-messagge-posthttp-127-0-0-18000-http-1-0-405-method-no