# Ajax send this error messagge POSThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/ [HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed 293ms]

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

it´s me again solvented the last error but now i have got this error, show me this messagge.
it´s supposed  to do a validation, and send a messagge error because i push enter with entry filed null, but it did not do it and show me a error.
I will put my code, please i will be very grateful if you help me.
[image]

Here the code

Url

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('products');
});

//Route::get('/', [Products::class, 'products'])->name('products');
Route::get('/add', [ProductsController::class, 'addProduct'])->name('add');
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    //

// Add 
    public function addProduct(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validates(
            [

                'name' => 'required|unique:products',
                'price' => 'required|unique:products',

            ],
            [

                'name.required' => 'Name is Required',
                'name.unique' => 'Product Already Exist',
                'price.required' => 'Name is Required',


            ]
            


        );

    }

}
```

product_js.blade.php

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
    </script> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click','.add_product', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let name= $('#name').val();
    let price= $('#price').val();
    $.ajax({
        URL: "{{ route('add') }}",
        method: 'post',
        data: {name:name, price:price},
        success:function(res){

        },error:function(err){

            let error= err.responseJSON;
            $.each(error.errors, function(index, value){
                $('.errMsgContainer').append('<span class="text-danger">'+ value+ '</span>' + '<br>')
            });
        }
    });


})

});
 </script>
```

products.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>AJAX cRUD</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxst.icons8.com/vue-static/landings/line-awesome/line-awesome/1.3.0/css/line-awesome.min.css">



  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="my-5 text-center">Ajax Crud </h1>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-success my-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addModal">Add Product </a> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
    </script> 





    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row"> 

    <div class="col-md-2"> </div> 
    <div class="col-md-8"> </div> 

    <div class="data-table"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered"> 
    <thead>  
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th> 
    <th scope="col">Name</th> 
    <th scope="col">Price</th> 
    <th scope="col">Action</th> 

</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th>1</th> 
<td>Mark</td>
<td>Mark</td> 
<td>Mark</td>  
<td>
<a href="" class=" btn btn-success" > <i class="las la-edit"></i></a> 
<a href="" class=" btn btn-danger" > <i class="las la-trash"></i></a> 

</td> 
</tr> 


    </tbody>

</table>

    </div> 

    </div> 

    </div> 

 @include('add_product_modal')
 @include('product_js')

  </body>
</html>
```

Modal form

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <form action="" method="post" id="addProductForm">
@csrf

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="addModalLabel">Add Product</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
        <div class="errMsgContainer"> 


        </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        
        <label for="name">Product Name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-controls" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"> 
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mt-2">
        
        <label for="price"> Price </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-controls" name="price" id="price"> 
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add_product">Save Product</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are sending a POST request to `/` but you only have GET route declared in your web.php for route '/'

Comment: 405 means you are trying to make a request to the api using the wrong request method (ie post instead of get)

Comment: the same error and i changed the routes, look the code  here

Comment: Route::get('/', [ProductsController::class, 'products'])->name('products');
Route::post('/product-add', [ProductsController::class, 'addProduct'])->name('add');

Answer (score -1):

first of all in your route change your route from get to post because you sending a post request from ajax

```
Route::post('/add', [ProductsController::class, 'addProduct'])->name('add');
```

and also after changing your route it's better to run

```
php artisan optimize
```

in terminal and then in your controller do it like this if you are using ajax this will check all your request for validation if it fails it will return the error in the response

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{
    //

// Add 
    public function addProduct(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'en_name' => 'required|unique:products',
            'ar_name' => 'required|unique:products',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json('errors' => $validator->errors());
        }

    }

}
```

then in your blade file inside ajax error you can do something like that to get all the response of the validation

```
                    if (data.responseJSON.errors) {
                        var errors = Object.values(data.responseJSON.errors);
                        errors.forEach(element => {
                            element.forEach(elements => {
                                console.log(element);
                            });
                        });
                    }
```

something like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click', '.add_product', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let name = $('#name').val();
            let price = $('#price').val();
            $.ajax({
                URL: "{{ route('add') }}",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    price: price
                },
                success: function(res) {

                },
                error: function(err) {
                    if (err.responseJSON.errors) {
                        var errors = Object.values(err.responseJSON.errors);
                        errors.forEach(element => {
                            element.forEach(elements => {
                                console.log(element);
                                $('.errMsgContainer').append('<span class="text-danger">' + value + '</span>' +
                                    '<br>')
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            });


        })

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? Why are you using code 460 for validation error? 460 => "Client closed the connection with the load balancer before the idle timeout period elapsed. Typically when client timeout is sooner than the Elastic Load Balancer's timeout"

Comment: Would still trigger the same error since there is no route "/add" that accepts a POST request (only GET request are accepted as is)

Comment: thanks for mentioning it i edited my answer

Comment: Hi man i tried but it did not work, i did all that you told me, and i have changed all but nothing have changed. show me the same error

Comment: the error is 405
Method Not Allowed that is the error now so i guess it´s not about sintaxis eroror

Comment: i am watching a little project in YT that i am following and, i just did it same as the professor but i dont really know why it doesn´t work on me

Comment: after changing the route did you run (php artisan optimize)?